# Latex Template and YAML

Tags: pandoc

I am currently working on a LATEX template to convert markdown/yaml documents into pdf resume through Latex and pandoc, via xetex. However the bold and emphasis commands are not translating through to pdf. An example script within the latex template (template.tex) is:

```
$if(education)$
\section*{Education}
\noindent
 $for(education)$
\note{$education.year$}\textbf{$education.subject$}$if(education.degree)$,$education.degree$$endif$\\
\emph{$education.institute$}$if(education.city)$, $education.city$$endif$\\[.2cm]
$endfor$
$endif$
```

The YAML source is:

```
education:
- year: 1867
  subject: Philology
  institute: Leipzig Universität
  city: Leipzig
- year: 1864
  subject: Abitur
  institute: Schulpforta
  city: Naumburg
```

However within the output pdf no text is bold or italic.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Which `pandoc` build command are you using? You have to specify your template explicitly when you are using custom template. Also, for debugging you should not output `pdf` right away, but you can write only `tex` file itself and inspect that.

Comment: I have nor problems with your template, please give some more details on what *exactly * you are doing

Answer (score 3):

If you haven a file `input.md`

```
---
education:
- year: 1867
  subject: Philology
  institute: Leipzig Universität
  city: Leipzig
- year: 1864
  subject: Abitur
  institute: Schulpforta
  city: Naumburg
---
```

and a template file `template.latex`

```
$if(education)$
\section*{Education}
\noindent
  $for(education)$
  \note{$education.year$}\textbf{$education.subject$}$if(education.degree)$,$education.degree$$endif$\\
    \emph{$education.institute$}$if(education.city)$, $education.city$$endif$\\[.2cm]
  $endfor$
$endif$
```

and you call pandoc like this

```
pandoc input.md --template template.latex --to latex
```

then the output will look like this

```
\section*{Education}
\noindent
    \note{1867}\textbf{Philology}\\
    \emph{Leipzig Universität}, Leipzig\\[.2cm]
    \note{1864}\textbf{Abitur}\\
    \emph{Schulpforta}, Naumburg\\[.2cm]
```

You can see `\emph` and `\textbf` are there